# Dynamically setting hystrix command javanica annotation properties at runtime from ldap

Tags: java, spring, configuration, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I want to change the properties to change dynamically at run-time. How do i set it and where? I want to stick to my current source of configuration and not move it to some property file or database.

```
@HystrixCommand(commandKey = "commandKey", fallbackMethod = "fallbackMethod", groupKey = "CacheGroupKey", commandProperties = { 
                @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "300") //MycustomconfigforthisClass.getTimeoutInMilliseconds()
})   
public Object get(Object data) {throw new RuntimeException("Lets go to fallback");}

public Object fallbackmethod(Object data) {return new Object();}
```